# Why is this an unstated assumption for rural spaces? - Test 3, Q27, by Mark Shepherd

Tags: meaning-in-context, understanding

Passage: [*Mastering the National Admissions Test for Law*](http://books.google.com.hk/books?id=xdgcAAAAQBAJ&lpg=PA146&ots=vktkrRqXNq&dq=%E2%80%98Spaces%20of%20consumption%3A%20from%20margin%20to%20centre%E2%80%99%20by%20Alexander%20Styhre%20and%20Tobias%20Engberg&hl=fr&pg=PA146#v=onepage&q=%E2%80%98Spaces%20of%20consumption:%20from%20margin%20to%20centre%E2%80%99%20by%20Alexander%20Styhre%20and%20Tobias%20Engberg&f=false) by Mark Shepherd, page 146.
= [Page 2, only first two paragraphs under the heading 'Spaces of Consumption'](http://www.ephemerajournal.org/sites/default/files/3-2styhreandengberg.pdf) Don't read the entire PDF.
Sorry, this passage is hard for me to apprehend, so I don't even know what to quote.

[Question 27, p.147](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=xdgcAAAAQBAJ&lpg=PA132&hl=fr&pg=PA147#v=onepage&q&f=false):

Which of the following is an unstated assumption made about rural spaces?
(a) They are capable of being moved to urban areas
(b) They represent the principal area of production
(c) They are capable of being contained in arcades
(d) They are totally different in character to urban spaces
(e) They are specifi cally linked with individual spaces of consumption

[From the answer key, p.237:](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=xdgcAAAAQBAJ&lpg=PA132&hl=fr&pg=PA236#v=onepage)

(b) CORRECT. It is said that ‘the spaces of production are paradoxically rural
spaces located within urban environments’, and a number of references are
made to new forms of rural spaces. Given that such references feature in a
discussion about production, the assumption must be made that rural spaces
represent the principal area of production, otherwise **the logic of the argument**
is lost.

1. Please simplify this abstract answer (to me) to explain why it's right? Why must we assume this?
2. Moreover, what's **the logic of the argument**?